# How to add quantity with product name to sales order grid in magento admin?

Tags: php, magento

How to show item name with quantity to sales order grid in magento admin?

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('total_qty_ordered'));
$collection->getSelect()->join(array(
            'item'=>$collection->getTable('sales/order_item')),
            'item.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id AND item.product_type="simple"',
            array(
                'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(item.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),
                'name' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(item.name SEPARATOR ", ")')
            ));

$this->addColumn('skus', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'index' => 'skus',
            'type' => 'text',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('NAME'),
            'index' => 'name',
            'type' => 'text'
        ));

$this->addColumn('total_qty_ordered', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
        'index' => 'total_qty_ordered',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order.total_qty_ordered',
        ));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do following, this is for to display qty in order grid column:

```
$this->addColumn('qty_ordered',
array(
    'header'=> $this->__('Quantity'),
    'align' =>'right',
    'type' => 'number',
    'index' => 'qty_ordered'
    'renderer' = new Custom_AddQty_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Qty()
)
);


class Custom_AddQty_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Qty extends 
 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action
 {
   public function render(Varien_Object $row)
 {
     return $this->_getValue($row);
 }

 public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
 {
     $val = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
     return intval($val);

 } 
 }
```